# Multiple schemas Entity Framework using MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, pomelo

Does anyone know if mysql supports multiple schemas in the same dbcontext using entity framework core?

I've been waiting for the solution to this problem, but I don't know if it was solved.

For those who don't know, the issue is the next:

When we specify the schema in mysql using the fluent mapping (`ToTable`) or class attribute (`Table("", Schema = "")`), the query provided by Pomelo just ignores the schema, or if you use '`HasDefaultSchema`', it will be ignored as well.

Is it a error in Pomelo (entity framework) or is it a mysql limitation?